# Using trapezoid rule for integration

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Can someone please help me fix the errors I made using the trapezoid rule? Apparently all my outputs are incorrect, aside the first one. I believe something is off with my choice for delta x. But I am not sure. Thank you!

Find values for $$I(x) = \int_0^x \sqrt{t^3 + 1}dt.$$ The values of $x$ are $0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2$.

$\textbf{Solution:}$ Let $I(x) = \int_0^x \sqrt{t^3 + 1}dt.$ For $x=0, I(x) = 0$. For $x = 0.5$ we have the following $$a=0, b = \frac{1}{2}, \text{ and } n = 5 \text{ so } \Delta x = \frac{b - a}{n} = \frac{1}{10}.$$

Next, $f(a) = f(0) = 1$, $$2f(x_1) = 2.00099$$ $$2f(x_2) = 2f(\frac{1}{5}) = 2.007984$$ $$2f(x_3) = 2f(\frac{3}{10}) = 2.02682016$$ $$2f(x_4) = 2f(\frac{2}{5}) = 2.0630075$$ $$f(x_5) = f(\frac{1}{2}) = 1.0606602$$

$\implies \frac{1}{2}$ $(f(a) + 2f(x_1) + 2f(x_2) + 2f(x_3) + 2f(x_4) + f(x_5)) = 0.5079$

For $x=1$ implies $a=0, b=1, n=5$. Also, $f(a) = 1.$ So $I(1) = \frac{1}{10} (f(a) + 2f(x_1) + 2f(x_2) + 2f(x_3) + 2f(x_4) + f(x_5)) = 1.1149$.

For $x=1.5, a = 0, b = 1.5, n = 5$ so $$I(1.5) = \frac{3}{20} (f(a) + 2f(x_1) + 2f(x_2) + 2f(x_3) + 2f(x_4) + f(x_5))$$ $$=\frac{3}{20} (1 + 2.026320 + 2.20545 + 2.62982 + 3.30333 + 2.091650) = 1.9885.$$

Finally, for $x=2; a = 0, b = 2, n=5$ we have $$I(2) = \frac{1}{5} (f(a) + 2f(x_1) + 2f(x_2) + 2f(x_3) + 2f(x_4) + f(x_5))$$ $$=\frac{1}{5} (1 + 2.0630 + 2.45926 + 3.3033 + 4.5148 + 3) = 3.2680.$$ And we are done.

Comment: The width of each strip should be $\frac{2}{4}$, not $0.1$. I belive that's your error.

Comment: @Moo its for x = 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2. It does not say anything else.

Comment: @A-levelStudent why? Does it not need to change as we go along x?

Comment: I actually don't understand what you've done. Assuming your question is copied here to the letter, then it doesn't specify how many strips each approximation should use, so you actually should be unable even to attempt the question. Now, assuming that the question is actually asking you to find only one approxiamtion using the trapezoid rule, but using the $5$ values for $x$ you have written, then my answer below applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trapezium/trapezoidal rule for the approximation of an definite integral, ie the area underneath a curve is given by
$$\frac{1}{2}h(y_0+2(y_1+y_2+y_3+...y_{n-1})+y_n)$$
where $h$ is the width of each trapezium/strip and $y_p$ is the value of the graph at $x_p$.
I think your area of confusion is about what the question is asking. I may be wrong, but I'd guess that the question is asking you to find an approximate area under the graph of
$y=\sqrt{t^3+1}$ between the origin and $x=2$,using the trapezoid rule, with $5$ values for $x$, **ie $4$ strips of equal width.** This is an important point: however many ordinates there are there will be $1$ less strips/trapezoids.

Now, although the width of each strip is immediately apparent, let's use the formal mathematical way of calculating it.

We have $a=0$ and $b=2$ and $n$, ie the number of strips, is $4$.
Now the formula for $h$, the width of each strip, is given by
$$h=\frac{b-a}{n}$$
which in your case is equal to $\frac{2-0}{4}=0.5$.
You should be able to continue from there. If not, ask for a hint or if you're really stuck, please ask for further help.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. So rather than finding a new scalar to multiple what is in the parentheses, we just use 0.5 the whole time and multiply it accordingly to each h.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure about what you just said-the value for $h$ remains constant throughout the calculation.

Comment: alright, thank you so much. I will adjust my solution.

Comment: @brucemcmc You're welcome, it's a pleasure to help :) Feel free to update me on your progress in the question.

Comment: @brucemcmc thanks for accepting my answer:) Was it useful in the end?